# ExceptionHandlerMiddleware|An unhandled exception has occurred: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have seen this issue in other posts, but I believe my situation may be different. My code works fine on localhost, but errors when I deploy to the web server. Using ASP.NET Core 2.0 and SQL Server 2012. I believe it has to do with my `UserType` class (`Model.LoggedInUserType`):

```
public string GetUserType(string LoginID)
{
     string user = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name;

     Employee employee = db.tblEmployee.FirstOrDefault(e => (e.FirstName + '.' + e.LastName) == user);
     string userType = employee.UserType;

     return userType;
}
```

UserTypeViewModel.cs

```
public string LoggedInUserType = BaseInfoClass.UserType;
```

Error (from log):

> 2018-09-12
> 16:06:04.9272|2|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker|Executed
> action
> ApostilleDNCv2.Controllers.TransactionController.UpdateTransaction
> (ApostilleDNCv2) in 906.2122ms  2018-09-12
> 16:06:04.9272|3|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession|Session started; Key:68a158b8-c8bb-9d16-6e66-8c1a3942f3be,
> Id:9c7a85af-15d4-b8c1-1286-c0ca515cb1e2  2018-09-12
> 16:06:04.9433||ERROR|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware|An
> unhandled exception has occurred: Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
> not set to an instance of an object.    at
> AspNetCore._Views_Shared_Components_Apostille_default_cshtml.d__22.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\TFS\Corporations\Development\Src\ApostilleDNCv2\ApostilleDNCv2\Views\Shared\Components\Apostille\default.cshtml:line
> 42
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

View (UpdateTransactionPost.cshtml) code:

```
<div class="col-lg-offset-2">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("Apostille", new { tid = Model.Trans.TransactionID })
</div>
<div class="col-lg-offset-2">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("Certificate", new { tid = Model.Trans.TransactionID })
</div>
```

View Component (Shared\Components\Apostille\default.cshtml - Line: 42):

```
<th class="txtctr" style="@(Model.LoggedInUserType.ToString() != "ADM" ? "display:none" : "" )">
                    @Html.DisplayName("Delete")
</th>
```

The purpose of the style reference is so that the delete (and certain other functions) are only visible/available to admins.

This web page displays a 400 error.  Other pages that do not rely on UserType display fine.

My questions: why does this work locally, but not from the web server?  How can I correct this issue, (hopefully) without rewriting the whole authentication scheme?

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2012 R2** version - only **2012** - fixed